# Lua nil value when trying to call function without args

Tags: delphi, lua

I'm trying to call callback in lua.
It is:

```
function Draw()
DrawText2D(0, 0, "Hi", 255, 255, 255, 0);
end
```

Using this code:

```
lua_getglobal(VLuaInstance, 'Draw');    
lua_pushnil(VLuaInstance);
if lua_pcall(VLuaInstance, 1, 0, 0) <> 0 then
AddStringToConsole('Lua module error: ' + lua_tostring(VLuaInstance, -1));
```

it's on delphi but equivalent to C code.

But i see error when frame needed to update in my game: "attempt to call a nil value".

Can you please give me right example for using pcall?

Comment: It probably means that `DrawText2D` is not defined.

Comment: Take a look at http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_pcall . `if lua_pcall(VLuaInstance, 1, 0, 0)` should change to `if lua_pcall(VLuaInstance, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: Also you dont need to push a nil value to the stack.